# how to strip XML data

Tags: sql, xml, database, rdbms

```
<ps>
    <p pdid="47" pv="x@xx.net" />
    <p pdid="49" pv="07827100000" />
    <p pdid="57" pv="dfdfdf Armstrong" />
    <p pdid="29" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="1" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="39" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="43" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="5" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="7" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="9" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="25" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="37" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="11" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="15" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="35" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="13" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="17" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="41" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="55" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="21" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="23" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="31" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="45" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="53" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="59" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="63" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="65" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="67" pv="LDC Data" />
    <p pdid="69" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="70" pv="[(null)]" />
    <p pdid="72" pv="12580672" />
    <p pdid="74" pv="CA1" />
</ps>
```

**Above data is in XML form- so how i can get PV values where PDID ="67"- please keep in mind the XML position of PDID keeps on changing from row by row.**

i have tried

`

```
 Select 
     iset.NAME AS Region   
    ,iset.custom_f
    ,CASE WHEN REPLACE(iset.custom_f.value('(/ps/p/pdid="67"/@pv)[30]',   'varchar(80)'),'[(null)]','') <> ''  THEN
             REPLACE(iset.custom_f.value('(/ps/p/pdid="67"/@pv)[30]', 'varchar(80)'),'[(null)]','')
        WHEN REPLACE(iset.custom_f.value('(/ps/p/pdid="67"/@pv)[31]', 'varchar(80)'),'[(null)]','') <> '' THEN
             REPLACE(iset.custom_f.value('(/ps/p/pdid="67"/@pv)[31]', 'varchar(80)'),'[(null)]','')
        WHEN REPLACE(iset.custom_f.value('(/ps/p/pdid="67"/@pv)[28]', 'varchar(80)'),'[(null)]','') <> '' THEN                   
             REPLACE(iset.custom_f.value('(/ps/p/pdid="67"/@pv)[28]', 'varchar(80)'),'[(null)]','')
        WHEN REPLACE(iset.custom_f.value('(/ps/p/pdid="67"/@pv)[29]', 'varchar(80)'),'[(null)]','') <> '' THEN                   
             REPLACE(iset.custom_f.value('(/ps/p/pdid="67"/@pv)[29]', 'varchar(80)'),'[(null)]','')
   END AS LeadSource  
  ,iset.Source
  ,ISET.oc_id
  ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(ISET.app_id,'') <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0
   END app   
from 
intial_set iset
```

`

as i mentioned the position keeps on changing so i need dont know how to cope it

Comment: i have provided code- your help really appreciated on this

Comment: Please, when asking the question, use all the tags that would enable us to help you. Your question is currently missing the tag specifying the RDBMS you're using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
REPLACE(
      iset.custom_f.value(
            '(/ps/p[@pdid="67"]/@pv)[1]'
          , 'varchar(80)'
      )
    ,'[(null)]'
    ,''
) AS LeadSource
```

instead of your case statement. you didn't specify the rdbms you're using, so i don't know whether your engine tolerates an xpath expression with an index out of range (this situation will occur if there is no `p` element having a `pdid` atrribute with value `67`). wrapping the given sql expression with an `COALESCE(..., '')`call should suffice, however.